# How can I authorize Google Calendar API with a Gmail profile when I get a 'Missing required parameter' error?

Tags: google-calendar-api, velo, invalid-request-uri

I'm trying to get my Google Calendar API authorized, but when I try to authorize the API using a gmail profile, I get the error "Missing required parameter: redirect_uri...Error 400 invalid_request" that visualizes another one of my Google profiles. Does anyone know how to get it to work?

I was expecting the API to be authorized.